# Ruby: Why not installable Active Admin in ruby 2.2 on rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using

- Ruby - 2.2.5p319
- Rails - 5.0.0.1
- Sqlite3 - 3.8.5

Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

I am getting error while installing `active_admin`

[image]

I also tried

```
bundle update
```

but still it fails

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, please paste, as text, the exact commands you ran, and the relevant/first error you saw in the error message(s) in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the README on activeadmin

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin#rails-5

> Active Admin master has preliminary support for Rails 5. To give it a try, these Gemfile changes may be needed:
>   `gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'`

Add `gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'` to your Gemfile and then run `bundle update`

The stacktrace you posted references inherited_resources so I think this is the issue.

Comment: @hieppk If this answered your question, could you mark it as the answer? Otherwise let me know what else is needed.